# Adding particle system deletes/hides my main material?

Tags: 3d-view, particles

When I add a particle system, it makes my main material suddenly die. See here:
https://streamable.com/rcycq3. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'm dumb, I had "Show Emitter" unchecked in Viewport Display. I thought emitters were weird white balls  but it's actually the layer/material that is emitting unsurprisingly